# Alter an image's position based on a key that is pressed?

Tags: javascript

The code here should take the element and move it to the left or right. However, the image is still in place.

```
       var posX = 100;

document.getElementById("ship").addEventListener("keydown", moveShip);
function moveShip(event) {
  if (event.key == "ArrowLeft") {
    posX -= 2;
  } else if (event.key == "ArrowRight") {
    posX += 2;
  }
}
```

HTML of the code is very basic, nothing much has been added here

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>ship</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img id="ship" src="spaceship.png" />
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script src="extensions.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS of the code is here

```
 canvas{
    border: 1px, solid, black;
}

html{
    background-color: black;
}

#ship{
    width: 100px;
  
}
```

Comment: Please add your HTML and CSS code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the image a relative position and set the left CSS property to move it.

```
<img id="ship" src="spaceship.png" style="position: relative;"/>
<script>
var posX = 100;
var ship = document.getElementById("ship");
ship.style.left = posX;
ship.addEventListener("keydown", moveShip);
function moveShip(event) {
  if (event.key == "ArrowLeft") {
    posX -= 2;
  } else if (event.key == "ArrowRight") {
    posX += 2;
  }
  ship.style.left = posX;
}
</script>
```